# How to have multiple, separate, instances of Trix / ActionText rich text areas on the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, trix, actiontext

I have a list of `commentable` models in my Rails view, represented by cards that each have their own comment form. The forms are identical (from the same partial), and have a `rich_text_area` for the commentable's `body` (defined as `has_rich_text :body` on the model, per the docs). It is close to the following (simplified) example:

```rb
<% @assignables.each do |assignables| %>
  <!-- omitted code displaying the assignable object -->

  <!-- ADD COMMENT FORM -->
  <%= form_with model: Comment.new do |form| %>
    <div class="">
      <%= form.hidden_field :commentable_id, value: assignable.id %>
      <%= form.hidden_field :commentable_type, value: assignable.class.name %>
      <%= form.rich_text_area :body, data: { controller: "mentions" } %>
      <%= form.submit "Submit", class: "button button-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Only the first form on the page (in DOM order) actually submits a `body` parameter. Network requests from any other form shows a blank `comment[body]` parameter. Additionally, if I add text to the 2nd form's input, then go back and submit the first form without touching it, the submission includes the input I entered into the 2nd form.

From this, I understand I need to override some attribute which is supposed to be unique. I've scoured the Rails docs and the Trix docs, but I haven't found anything which indicates how to make Rails do this override such that Trix accepts it.

What attribute do I override, and how?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the answer is simple: override the `id` attribute of the rich text area to include a unique value like a primary key, and Rails handles the rest.

E.g.:

```
<%= form.rich_text_area :body, data: { controller: "mentions" }, 
  id: "commentable_#{commentable.id}_comment" %>
```

Translates to:

```
<form …>
  <input id="commentable_1_comment" value="Editor content goes here" type="hidden" name="content">
  <trix-editor input="commentable_1_comment"></trix-editor>
</form>
```

Now every instance of the text area has a unique ID (rather than the generic `new_comment`) and the hidden inputs all submit their values correctly.

For reference: The [Trix documentation](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#populating-with-stored-content) show what the HTML is supposed to look like at the after ERB is done with it, but the Rails `rich_text_area` docs don't indicate anything about attributes you might want to override.